# Google webmastertools soft 404 - How to update google search after updating it to 200

Tags: google-search-console, google-search

My site has many modules which are indexed by google.

Recently there has been a database problem so the site was not appearing well like many links returned 404 i think.

Now i have make it working and all the content what previously google indexed are as it were.

How do we update google that i have corrected and the pages which sent 404 are not 200?

That is now i wanted to tell google that the urls which sent 404 are now working fine so that google will update it soon before it removes from its database.

Comment: You mention "soft" 404 in the title, but you appear to describe proper 404s in your question. A soft-404 is when you don't actually return a 404 status code, but simply a message that states "Not Found" with a 200 status code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell Google you have corrected the pages that previously returned a 404 status code... In Google Webmaster Tools > Health > Crawl Errors, pick the "Not Found" errors and in the table below, select all the 404s you have fixed and click the "MARK AS FIXED" button.

[image: Fixing 404 errors in Google Webmaster Tools]